# Using REST API with admin username and password is good or safe in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, rest-api, curl, token

I am using REST API in Magento 2.
For using in Guest user i want to create admin token so i have used CURL Request like this.

```
$ch = curl_init();
$userData = array("username" => "admin", "password" => "password");
$ch = curl_init("http://127.0.0.1/mag/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:   application/json", "Content- 
Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));
$token = curl_exec($ch);
```

and $token is generated.

**But I have a question regarding this that it it safe to use this in my Controller file if yes then it is good or not please suggest any other solution.**

Token Generated from ADMIN

[image]

Any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you shouldn't allocate an admin's privileges to a guest user or any customer user for that matter. There is a reason why guest users can access only specific resources. I don't think it would be a good idea to allow any user to perform any admin operations.

Instead you should limit yourself to what Magento allows guest users to do or create custom API endpoints if you really need something else, but I suggest you don't use an admin's credentials to allow a guest user to do stuff on your shop.

As per https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html#admin-and-customer-access-tokens:

> The Magento web API framework allows guest users to access resources
> that are configured with the permission level of anonymous. Guest
> users are users who the framework cannot authenticate through existing
> authentication mechanisms. As a guest user, you do not need to, but
> you can, specify a token in a web API call for a resource with
> anonymous permission.

---

***LE:***

- **Admins** use a specific token obtained when calling `/rest/v1/integration/admin/token` (with admin username and password as payload) and a specific different endpoints available for them https://magento.redoc.ly/2.3.6-admin/
- **Customers** have a different token than the admins and it is obtained by calling `/rest/V1/integration/customer/token` (with customer username and customer account password as payload) and have access to a specific subset of endpoints only https://magento.redoc.ly/2.3.6-customer/
- **Guest users** don't need a token to be generated (and you can't generate one AFAIK since you don't have identification elements for a guest user on your shop) and have access to a limited subset of endpoints (those marked with anonymous in the webapi.xmls), list available here https://magento.redoc.ly/2.3.6-guest/

So basically, you can't generate an admin token for the customer or the guest users, they have access to resources which are not the admin ones. If you generate admin tokens and give them those tokens, then you no longer are using the subset of endpoints allocated to customers or guest users, you are using the admin endpoints and you basically 'are an admin' when you request them. So be careful with this.

Comment: Thanks for your response @diana 
As, i can see on using REST API it will required to generate token so how to generate that token if i doesn't use http://127.0.0.1/mag/rest/V1/integration/admin/token that api to generate token.
Or you mean to say i will used that backend generated access token.

Comment: What I wanted to say is that specific operations are not allowed for guest users. Guest users are allowed to access only specific resources- these ones https://magento.redoc.ly/2.3.6-guest/ the other operations are allowed only for customers which are registered and admins which you can retrieve tokens for.

Comment: Thanks for the response so, you mean to say that if any logged in user used REST API then it is OK to used that token but if any guest user comes in then i will not used that token i will used admin token which is provided in admin dashboard.

Comment: actually no. please check the update on my above answer.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation.Actually my scenario is different
If i want to used if any Customers/Guest User click on any product it will be saved on database and then added to cart so is it safe to use that ADMIN generated Acess Token to achieve that or any other thoughts will you please share.